# How to submit a string in a Request using C# for Eggplant Performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eggplant

Greeting for 2022.

I am currently evaluating a performance tool called Eggplant performance using a C#.

The application I am testing against has a user set password that requires me to insert certain random characters of my password.

Example:
Password = password1
Then the application will make me insert 3characters of my password randomly.

Each required field gets an ID that is between 7-9 characters long, but always longer than 6 and shorter than 10.

The payload down the wire then looks like this:

B806b8220=s&e210cdd9=s&cd5d5105=d&landingpage=express etc.

I have been able to do the work correlating those fields and and getting the logic around that.

What I am struggling with, and it is because I do not have a dev background is submitting this back down the wire.

The correlated build up value looks like below:

[Passphrase is set as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvS6q.png)

And where i need to submit it is:

[Submit the Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaseV.png)

I receive a bunch of errors all over the place.

Any guidance into the right way will be much appreciated.
(Using Visual Studio 2015)

////Additional Information:

The code where the extraction happens. I extract 9 ID's (as the password1 is 9 characters).

I then Say if the ID extracted is bigger than 6, use that plus add the correlated password piece. This works 100%

```
ExtractionCursor extractionCursor41 = new ExtractionCursor(); 
                    if (response41.Find(extractionCursor41, "Enter only the required characters of", ActionType.ACT_EXIT_VU, true, SearchFlags.SEARCH_IN_BODY))
                    {
                        Set("c_surephraseIDs_41", response41.ExtractList(extractionCursor41, "name=\"", "\" id=\"", "viLabel=\"Password 9\" />", true, 9, ActionType.ACT_EXIT_VU, SearchFlags.SEARCH_IN_BODY));
                    }
                    
                    if (extractionCursor41.Succeeded)
                    {
                        WriteMessage("Items extracted to list variable: c_surephraseIDs_41...");
                        List<string> valuesList = Get<List<string>>("c_surephraseIDs_41");
                        foreach (string listItem in valuesList)
                        {
                            WriteMessage(String.Format("Item: {0}", listItem));
                        }

                        List<string> Array2 = Get<List<string>>("c_surephraseIDs_41");
                        List<string> Array1 = new List<string> { "p", "a", "s", "s", "w", "o", "r", "d", "1" };
                        List<string> Array3 = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
                        int j = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                        {
                            
                            if (Array2[i].Length > 6)
                            {                            
                                Array3[j] = Array2[i] + "=" + Array1[i];
                                WriteMessage(Array3[j]);
                                j++;
                            }
                        }

                        string Passphrase = Array3[0] + "&" + Array3[1] + "&" + Array3[2];
 

                    }
                    
                    // Rule: Verify that the result code matches what was recorded
                    response41.VerifyResult(HttpStatus.OK, ActionType.ACT_WARNING);
                }
```

Then in the request where this is parsed back to the website:

```
using (Request request44 = WebBrowser.CreateRequest(HttpMethod.POST, url44, 44))
            {
                request44.SetReferer(new Url(protocol1, onlinebankinguat3, "/absa-online/login.jsp"));
                request44.SetHeader("Origin", "https://onlinebankinguat3.absa.co.za");
                request44.SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                Form postData44 = new Form();
                postData44.CharEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                //The below 3 are originally as per the recording.
                //postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("B3391b84d", "a", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                //postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("B54824db9", "r", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                //postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("fa2ebc87", "d", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                //The below is the one I am trying to send over the wire
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("",GetString("Passphrase"), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                //
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("landingpage", "express", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("dsp", "false", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("dspid", "0", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("dspreferer", "null", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("goto", "", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("", "", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("", "", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("nonce", "0", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                postData44.AddElement(new InputElement("uniq", GetMillisecondsSinceEpoch(-5) /* Replaced timestamp 1641064306006 (2022-01-01T21:11:46.006000+02:00) */ , Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
                request44.SetMessageBody(postData44);
```

When it comes to building the string Passphrase I can see that it works correctly:

[The string builds correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXAaa.png)

And when it comes to the sending of the request this is the response:

[The errors that is logged once I try send the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOPS3.png)

Comment: [Never post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 
Could you paste the errors.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have updated the main thread. Thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{

  if (Array2[i].Length > 6)
  {
    Array3[j] = Array2[i] + "=" + Array1[i];

    if (j == 0)
    {
      Set<string>("PPleft1", Array2[i]);
      Set<string>("PPright1", Array1[i]);
    }
    if (j == 1)
    {
      Set<string>("PPleft2", Array2[i]);
      Set<string>("PPright2", Array1[i]);
    }
    if (j == 2)
    {
      Set<string>("PPleft3", Array2[i]);
      Set<string>("PPright3", Array1[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hendri, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)